# install mono rpm like yum?

Tags: centos, yum, mono

I want to install the mono RPM like it would be if I installed it through yum. What I mean is that when you install the rpm it puts everything in /opt/novell/. I want it to put in /usr/bin/, etc like yum does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yum is not responsible for where the files are placed; that is determined when the package is built. If you want to change this then you'll need to get the SRPM, modify it, and rebuild it.

Comment: So yum doesn't use the same rpms? Do you know of a yum repo with 2.10.1?

Comment: yum doesn't care about the RPMs; it will install what it is instructed to install. The problem is with the RPMs themselves.